# How to serve up JSON files in MERN stack app

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am currently working on building a MERN stack application that is serving as an admin center/backend for a game. My front end dev needs to be able to connect his end to my end points from the database.

My question is how do I set up a route in my application that serves up a json file from my MongoDB to the webpage? I don't want to render the json file to a table or anything like that, just need it to be raw json. Any advice is much appreciated!

Here's a small example of what I mean:

[JSON file in web browser example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpw7z.png)

Here is my server side server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

//Connect Database
connectDB();

//Initialize Middleware - Allows for us to use 'req.body'
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

//Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/userplayers', require('./routes/userPlayers'));

//Serve React in Production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    //Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

and here is my client side app.js:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import Players from "./components/pages/Players.js";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import General from './components/pages/General';
import ContactState from "./context/contact/ContactState";
import AuthState from "./context/auth/AuthState";
import AlertState from "./context/alert/AlertState";
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import Test from "./components/pages/Test";

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthState>
      <ContactState>
        <AlertState>
          <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar />
              <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                  <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
                  <Route exact path="/players" component={Players} />
                  <Route exact path="/general" component={General} />
                  <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </AlertState>
      </ContactState>
    </AuthState>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I was able to figure this out! I needed to add a 'GET' route in my server.js, add a callback function in the Model so I can export the module and setup a 'GET' in my route folder.